# Проверка всех условий в функции

Tags: python, функции, циклы, условия

есть следующий кусочек кода, в нём описан метод определенного класса.
Как сделать так, что бы эта функция завершалась только тогда, когда все условия выполнены. Причём не очень хочется пользоваться оператором **and**, т.к. если одно из условий не выполняется, должна сработать функция **print**, и вывести на экран, почему условие не выполнилось. Вот код:

```
def rename(self):

name = input('Введите новое имя счёта: ')

while name:

    while name[0].isdigit() == True:
        print('\nИмя счёта не должно начинаться с цифры')
        name = input('Введите новое имя счёта: ')
        continue

    while len(name) <= 3:
        print('\nИмя счёта должно быть длиннее 3-ех символов')
        name = input('Введите новое имя счёта: ')
        continue

    while name.isprintable() == False:
        print('\nИмя счёта не должно содержать посторонних символов')
        name = input('Введите новое имя счёта: ')
        continue

    while name.isspace() == True:
        print('\nИмя счёта не должно содержать только пробельные символы')
        name = input('Введите новое имя счёта: ')
        continue

    while name[0].isspace() == True:
        print('\nИмя счёта не должно начинаться с пробела')
        name = input('Введите новое имя счёта: ')
        continue
```

Сейчас это работает так. Если условие не выполнилось (к примеру мы ввели имя с цифрой в начале), принт выведет на экран почему, мы конечно же исправляем его, но снова допускаем ошибку (к примеру ввели имя не длиннее 3ех символов), мы снова исправляем ошибку, но если снова введём имя начиная с цифры, ошибка не обнаружится. Расскажите как исправить, на ум приходит только громадное повторение кода, где условия меняются местами по расположению выше\ниже.

Пробовал сделать вложенные циклы, но результата особо не дало, так же проскакивало через одно из условий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверяйте сразу все ошибки

```
while True:
    name = input('Введите новое имя счёта: ')
    err = []
    if name[0].isdigit() :
        err.append('\nИмя счёта не должно начинаться с цифры')
    if len(name) <= 3:
        err.append('\nИмя счёта должно быть длиннее 3-ех символов')
    if not name.isprintable():
        err.append('\nИмя счёта не должно содержать посторонних символов')
    if name.isspace():
        err.append('\nИмя счёта не должно содержать только пробельные символы')
    if name[0].isspace():
        err.append('\nИмя счёта не должно начинаться с пробела')
    if err:
       print(''.join(err))
    else:
        break
```